# NiftyNet Selective Sampler batches not taken from mix of volumes?

Tags: niftynet

I'm training on three CT volumes using the Selective Sampler to ensure that enough samples are taken around the RoI (due to class imbalance), with some random samples. I'm also augmenting the data by scaling, rotation, and flipping, which takes a significant amount of time whenever samples are created.

Setting sample_per_volume to some large value (such as 32768) and batch_size to 128, it seems like NiftyNet will do 256 iterations of 128 samples just taken from the first volume, then switch to samples only taken from the 2nd volume (with a sharp jump in loss) and so on. I want each batch of 128 samples to be a roughly even mixture of samples taken from all of the training volumes.

I've tried setting sample_per_volume to roughly 1/3 of the batch_size so that samples are reselected for each iteration, but this slows down each iteration from around 2s to 50-60s.

Am I misunderstanding something? Or is there a way around this to ensure my batches are made up of samples from a mix of all the training data? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The samples populate a queue of length `queue_length`, given in the `.ini` file. They are then randomly taken from the queue to populate the batch.

I would make the `queue_length` parameter bigger. Then it will be filled with data from several different subjects.